# delete words from given file by cut

Tags: linux

could any one help me to remove this words from this column
I have tried this but did not work

```
cat ./bbc1.csv | cut -f3 -d' ' | grep -v [a-z]
```

---

5.015
5.015
0.001
0.001
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
60.789
60.789
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.001
0.002
0.002
5.015
5.015
0.001
0.001
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.002
0.001
0.001
seen
flows:
flows/second:
2017-01-05
processed:

could any one  help me please to do this by using cut command

Comment: what is the desired output? please take a look at [formatting](/Help/formatting).

Comment: thank you because this is the first time i use this site

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat ./bbc1.csv | cut -f3 -d' ' | grep -v ^[a-z]
```